# How do I get Python to notice a change in the system timezone while running?

Tags: python

If I change my computer's timezone while a Python program is running, that program continues to use the old timezone for calculations and conversions unless I restart the program.

This causes trouble in situations such as parsing the output of commands which use local time, such as `net stats svr` in Windows. Converting such a parsed local time to a Unix timestamp with `time.mktime(local_naive_datetime.timetuple())` returns an incorrect timestamp unless the program is restarted because it assumes the local time is in the old timezone.

A simple example demonstrating this problem: call `datetime.datetime.now()`, change the system timezone, and call the function again. The second call returns the local time in the old timezone.

Is there a function or other method I can use to tell Python to recheck the system timezone without restarting a long-running script?

I am running Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you specify what system you're on?(python version, OS, etc...). python 2.7 on OSX 10.8 doesn't exhibit this behaviour. I ran datetime.datetime.now() and it gave me the correct local time, changed my timezone to china and it gave me the time in china -- matching the system clock both times -- when run again(using the python REPL).

Comment: May I add though, that python-dateutil keeps detecting the local timezone as the first one even after it's changed, so there is obviously something weird going on here

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a function. 
You can call  `time.tzset()`  and  you can use `time.tzname`  to get the time zone information.

Please take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.tzset

Comment: According to the documentation you linked, as well as a quick test I did, `time.tzset()` is not available on Windows. In addition, `time.tzname` remains as the old timezone after a system timezone change unless I restart the python script/REPL.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked to detect the change.  Not exactly production quality though.

```
import os
import time
print(time.ctime(time.time()))
inp = input('change time and press enter')
f = open('newtimezone','w')
f.close()
print(time.ctime(os.stat('newtimezone').st_mtime))
```